# How to get the original gradient colors of a LinearGradient?

Tags: swiftui

Suppose we have a `LinearGradient` instance in hand, is there any way we can get the original array of colors used in that gradient?

Or, is there a way to reverse the colors/direction used in that gradient directly?

Comment: No. `LinearGradient` is a rendered view, `Gradient` is model, so pass model here-and-there.

Comment: @Asperi Is it possible to reverse the direction of the linear gradient?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to reverse the colors/direction used in that gradient directly?

SwiftUI is reactive, so make gradient state dependent and modify state - view will redraw, like

```
struct DemoReverseGradient: View {
    @State private var reversed = false

    var body: some View {
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(stops: [
            .init(color: Color.red, location: 0),
            .init(color: Color.blue, location: 1)
        ]),     startPoint: reversed ? .leading : .trailing,
                 endPoint: reversed ? .trailing : .leading)
        .frame(height: 200)
        .onTapGesture {
            self.reversed.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```